# Evaluate the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\psi(n)$ be a non-negative function such that $\psi(n)$ $\geq$ $1$ for all real $n$. Also let for any integer $k$ between two consecutive squares $\psi(k)$ $>$ $\psi(k+1)$. Also for two consecutive squares (say $t^2$ and $(t+1)^2$) we have $\psi((t+1)^2)$ $<$ $\psi(t^2)$. Assuming that when $n$ tends to infinity, $\psi(n)$ tends to  $l$, find the value of $l$.

I think that the value is $1$. This is because since of the conditions of the question. But I cannot obtain a completely rigorous proof (or disproof) of this assertion.

Comment: I don't understand what the second condition adds: since $t^2 < (t+1)^2$, we already know that $$\psi(t^2) > \psi(t^2+1) > \ldots > \psi\left((t+1)^2\right)$$

Comment: It is bounded from below and the function is decreasing, so it converges to the infimum. I think.

Comment: Why cannot you have $$\psi(x) = 2 + \frac{1}{x} \to 2$$ instead? By this example it can converge to any limit...

Comment: @gt6989b: because for that function you don't have $\psi(x) \geq 1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @rubik Missed the *all real numbers* part, thank you

Comment: The function $\psi(x) = e^{-x} + 1$ satisfies all the conditions. Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \psi(x) = 1$ the answer must be $1$.